# Not allowed to upload any images to questions?

Tags: discussion

was trying to post photos (diagram) to clarify the ideas, but I coudn't do that because of the following:

"We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images."

I guess it's 2 reasons:

You have to be more than 10 reputation points. (Which i have)
You cannot be a new user. (Which I am)
What do I have to do to become a non-new user? Is it related to time (how much time?) or is it related to reputation (how many points?)

Comment: The message is pretty self explanatory...

Comment: As a general note, you typically want to *shy* away from images to display code, stack traces or other failures.  Images only really make sense with something to do with a GUI backed up by code, and not just in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need images in your question, there's another thing you can do:

You can *post a link to the image*. Other users (which have enough rep to post images) can then verify that it's not porn-spam or anything and edit your question to embed the image, usually from the First Posts review queue. In fact, if you take a look at [my own edit history](//stackoverflow.com/users/6388243/some-person?tab=activity&sort=revisions), you'll see that I do this *a lot*.

Comment: But please, please make sure you actually need an image first.